# Is it possible to use ejs files also as static files in the standard "public" folder? (Node / Express)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

I'm learning Node/Express/socket.io - I followed an instruction using ejs files to define my pages and dynamically change them.

The issue is I want to use the feature of namespaces by socket.io. If user 'John' is in room '1', he should not get any messages from user 'Jack' in room '2'. To visually achieve this in the frontend, I would need to manipulate the html file (or ejs) file on the client site. However it seems ejs saves all the files on severside in the folder "views" - thus currently 'John' and 'Jack' would see all messages, even being in two different rooms.

Is there any option to somehow to define the "chat-page" to be static and keept in the "public" folder, where as the rest of the ejs files remain in the views folder?

Comment: Please describe your actual chat problem with namespaces in more detail because you should be able to solve that entirely in just your client-side code without manipulating the files themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean, but like the comment above has said this can be entirely done on the frontend. You can serve the ejs file using res.render or send a static html file using res.sendFIle() thats totally up to you depending on your needs. From within your frontend you could use js to receive events (get messages or whatever you're trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to be res.sendFile() but not sure if this is the best one.